# Does a Registrar forwarding your Domain to your hosting site url, violate Google AdSense TOS?

Tags: web-hosting, google-adsense, web-crawlers

NameCheap offers to forward traffic to a url of your choosing, which is really handy if you are using a free web hosting service, and/or ever want to move to try another free host someday.

However, I don't want to save $50 on hosting fees only to get BANNED from Google's adsense for violating it's URL Forwarding TOS.

So aside from the technical aspects of whether or not Google's crawlers will actually forward to the forwarded domain or not, the big question is, can this be done or will you be banned?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're using a 301 redirect [permanently moved] you will be fine. However, if you are not, then most likely you will be banned - especially if you have duplicate content on it.

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/AdSense/thread?tid=4654ef26bb407b38&hl=en

However, your question is kinda vague so if you're saying you have a domain named, www.domaina.com and you want to forward it to a free host that's url is yourdomain.domainb.com then the answer would be yes. However, I suggest getting a cheap web host and just routing the nameserver instead of using a free host. This will ensure that you don't have any banning and you can switch hosts whenever you want and update the nameservers to whatever the new one would be for your new host at any time.